# Eclipse Installer cannot find Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been trying to install Eclipse but every time I click the installer it opens this webpage:

Webpage screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhYPQ.png)

I have the latest version of Java installed on my laptop. Can anyone help? I use Windows 10.

Comment: What's the error you are seeing?

Comment: Which Java version do you have installed? (Run on the command line "java -version")

Comment: Where is Java installed? How did you install it? What exact version do you have installed? It is possible you just need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to allow Eclipse to find the installation.

Comment: Caleb - I hope your problem is resolved as you thanked on my solution, appreciate if you can accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Accept the License Agreement` for downloading and instal JDK 1.8 (Windows x64 for 64 bit & Windows x86 for 32 bit) and you should be fine.

Make sure you update your `Path` and add `JAVA_HOME` variable with path to JDK and its bin so that eclipse and all other software can find installed java.

1. `what is java version on my laptop?` :
   https://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.xml
2. `JDK download` :

   - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
   - `latest versions` : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
3. `32 or 64 bit windows` :

   - https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21726/how-do-i-know-if-im-running-32-bit-or-64-bit-windows-answers/
   - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15056/windows-7-32-64-bit-faq
4. `Set PATH variable` : https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml
5. `Set JAVA_HOME variable` : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Glad to help, please accept the answer and vote up answer to help others with same problem in future! Here are instructions : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

Just download the one of the jdk which shows in the link, JDK1.8 is preferable, I think after installing jdk it will not give same error, and it doesn't matter which version of Java you have installed, just install jdk 1.8

Comment: Thank you, this sorted the problem!